# MYSQL - Select where two fields are equal in two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in the same database:

```
T1 -   
ID  
Make  
Model  
Series  
Variant   
MSN  

T2-  
ID  
Make  
Model
MSN
Reg  
location  
uname  
notes
```

`T1` is the aircraft table, and `T2` is the logging table. In `T2` we can have many logs for each aircraft - so for instance I can log an aircraft with registration of G-VNEW at Manchester and Liverpool. So if that aircraft at a later date is sold to another company and it then changes its reg to G-DCAA I could then obivously see the same aircraft at different locations again.

I want to create a list outputted on my webpage that will show all the fields in `T2` which equal Make/Serial in `T1`. Is this along the right lines :

```
Select * from T2 where T2.Make=T1.Make and T2.MSN=T1.MSN order by T2.date DESC
```

The reasoning behined the make / MSN selection is that Boeing / Airbus could have aircraft with the same MSN, unlikely but possible.

Comment: I do not see a Serial in either table. Is Serial a unique field? If so, why do you need the Make?

Comment: Hi yes my bad- Serial - should be MSN (Manafacturers Serial Number) The serial number could apply to two different aircraft of two different manafacturers.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd duplicate Make, Model in both. ID in T1 would be the unique primary key; then make a LogID in T2 which would T2's unique primary key and also have ID as a col in T2 to tie it back to a specific T1 entry. Or maybe I'm missing something....

Comment: Hi. Yes you are correct I will remove the Model, however the Make e.g.Boeing or Airbus will help assertain the difference between an Airbus Aircraft with the same Serial (for instance: MAKE - Airbus, Serial 22 would be different from Make: Boeing Serial 22) although the make is different the serial is the same, so this would prevent a sighting of the Boeing aircraft being logged against the Airbus one, does that help?

Comment: I understand how you mean now, I think perhaps I was or I am over complicating this! I would vote your comment up if I was able to!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use INNER JOIN here, as bcz you are using other table to compare the values.

```
Select * from T2
Inner Join T1
On T2.Make=T1.Make
where T2.Make=T1.Make and T2.Serial=T1.Serial
Order By T2.date DESC
```

Try this out..Hope, it will work for you...Will be waiting for your feedback.